# how to make locateCenterOnScreen more accurate -PYTHON-, -WINDOWS-

Tags: python, windows, automation, image-recognition, pyautogui

Hello my goal is to be able to make my bot click the thing of my choosing on any screen size because I think that is the main issue. Ive tried to decrease the confidence level but it just ends up clicking something else with the same general color. ive tested it with an EXACT image and it clicks the correct spot so its not like the coordinates are off or anything its just the image recognition.

These are the images to go by

(X1, NextLesson, Arrow)
[image: X1]
[image: NextLesson]
[image: Arrow]

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random

def NextLesson():
    keepGoing = True
    while keepGoing == True:
        counter = 0
        nl_coordinates = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('images/nextLesson.png', confidence=0.4)
        print(nl_coordinates)  # This will print out where it is
        if nl_coordinates:
            print(f"I can see it at {nl_coordinates}")
            pyautogui.click(nl_coordinates)
            keepGoing = False
        else:
            print("I cannot see it.")

def Arrow():
    keepGoing = True
    while keepGoing == True:
        counter = 0
        arrow_coordinates = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('images/arrow.png', confidence=0.4)
        print(arrow_coordinates)  # This will print out where it is
        if arrow_coordinates:
            print(f"I can see it at {arrow_coordinates}")
            pyautogui.click(arrow_coordinates)
            keepGoing = False
        else:
            print("I cannot see it.")

def X1():
    keepGoing = True
    while keepGoing == True:
        counter = 0
        x1_coordinates = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('images/x1.png', confidence=0.4)
        print(x1_coordinates)  # This will print out where it is
        if x1_coordinates:
            print(f"I can see it at {x1_coordinates}")
            pyautogui.click(x1_coordinates)
            keepGoing = False
        else:
            print("I cannot see it.")

while True:
    counter = 0
    counter2 = 0
    true = True

    time.sleep(2)
    X1()#
    time.sleep(8)
    NextLesson()#
    time.sleep(10)
    Arrow()#
    print("calibration complete ")


    time.sleep(5)
    cords = pyautogui.position()

    while counter != 1800:
        time.sleep(60)
        pyautogui.click(cords) #clicking where ouse is at
        print("clicked")
        counter += 60
        print(counter)
    if counter == 1800:
        time.sleep(5) #stops code for 5 secs
        X1() #clicks mouse to x button
        print("clicked x")

        time.sleep(5) #stops code for 5 secs
        NextLesson() #clicks mouse to the assignment button
        print("clicked assignemnt")

        time.sleep(15) #stops code for 2 secs
        Arrow() #clicks mouse to the second assignment button
        print("clicked 2nd assignment button ")

        time.sleep(5) #waits 5secs to put cursor at position
        cords = pyautogui.position() #grabs position
        print("grabbed position")
```

Comment: I am aware that "this isn't the best way to do that" but I am still learning and just need help for this stump

Comment: you could try setting it to grayscale and increasing the confidence value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use opencv-python to perform multiscale template matching. The idea is to scale the template image and attempt to locate the resized template in the screenshot. The code below (adapted from [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/26/multi-scale-template-matching-using-python-opencv/)) loops over 50 scaling parameters in the range [0.25,2] and selects the one the that provides the best match. You might want to decrease the range or number of scaling parameters for efficiency. It is also better to save the correct scaling parameter and reuse it for multiple images.

```
import cv2
import pyscreeze
import numpy as np
import imutils
import pyautogui

def template_match_with_scaling(image,gs=True,confidence=0.8):
"""
Locate an image and return a pyscreeze box surrounding it. 
Template matching is done by default in grayscale (gs=True)
Detect image if normalized correlation coefficient is > confidence (0.8 is default)
"""
    templateim = pyscreeze._load_cv2(image,grayscale=gs) # template image
    (tH, tW)   = templateim.shape[:2]

    screenim_color = pyautogui.screenshot() # screenshot of image
    screenim_color = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(screenim_color),cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    if gs is True:
       screenim = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(screenim_color),cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    else:
       screenim = screenim_color

    #try different scaling parameters and see which one matches best
    found = None #bookeeping variable for the maximum correlation coefficient, position and scale
    scalingrange = np.linspace(0.25,2,num=50)
    for scale in scalingrange:
        resizedtemplate = imutils.resize(templateim,  width = int(templateim.shape[1]*scale) ) # resizing with  imutils maintains the aspect ratio
        r = float(resizedtemplate.shape[1])/templateim.shape[1] # recompute scaling factor
        result = cv2.matchTemplate(screenim, resizedtemplate, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED) # template matching using the correlation coefficient
        (_, maxVal, _, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(result) #returns a 4-tuple which includes the minimum correlation value, the maximum correlation value, the (x, y)-coordinate of the minimum value, and the (x, y)-coordinate of the maximum value
        if found is None or maxVal > found[0]:
           found = (maxVal, maxLoc, r)

    (maxVal, maxLoc, r) = found
    if maxVal > confidence:
       box = pyscreeze.Box(int(maxLoc[0]), int(maxLoc[1]), int(tW*r), int(tH*r) )
       return box
    else:
       return None

def locate_center_with_scaling(image,gs=True):
    loc = template_match_with_scaling(image,gs=gs) 
    if loc:
       return pyautogui.center(loc)
    else:
       raise Exception("Image not found")

#sample usage 
coords = locate_center_with_scaling('images/arrow.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer I found is taking a more accurate photo of what I need like trying to remove the background as much greyscale=ture and adding more confidence