# button to take frame screenshot

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

can someone help me take a screnshot of a specific frame?

been playing with these, but cant seem to specify just the frame

```
import pyautogui
#im1 = pyautogui.screenshot()
#im1.save('my_screenshot.png')
#im2 = pyautogui.screenshot('my_screenshot2.png')


from tkinter import *
import time
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import pyautogui as pg

# Create an instance of tkinter frame or window
win = Tk()

# Set the size of the window
win.geometry("700x350")


frm2shoot = Frame(win)
frm2shoot.grid(column=0, row=0)
lbl = Label(frm2shoot, width=16, text="testing testing:", justify=LEFT, anchor="w").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, pady=2)

# Define a function for taking screenshot
def screenshot():
   random = int(time.time())
   filename = "/Users/ricardosimoes/Desktop/"+ str(random) + ".jpg"
   ss = pg.screenshot(filename)
   ss.show()
   frm2shoot.deiconify()


# Create a Button to take the screenshots
button = Button(win, text="Take Screenshot", font=('Aerial 11 bold'), background="#aa7bb1", foreground="white", command=screenshot)
button.grid(column=5, row=0)

win.mainloop()
```

Anyone have any idea how to do this??

Comment: Assuming the location of the frame is fixed on the screen, you can use the `region` argument of `pg.screenshot` to screen capture the specific region occupied by the frame

Comment: PG11 thanks but how do i know what is the specific region of the frame?

Comment: You will have to do it by trial and error. The `region` argument [takes](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html) a four-tuple value representing the left, top, width, and height of the region in pixels. Start with a random four-tuple and adjust the values until your screenshot spans just the frame. The screen coordinate system is explained [here](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html)

Comment: PG11 thanks but will that work in diferent resolutions??

Comment: It will not because the region coordinates will be different. To work with a new resolution, you could have the user move the mouse to the boundaries of the region and get the new coordinates using `pyautogui.position()`

Comment: Another solution is to scale the region coordinates to fit the new resolution. It should be possible to automatically find the scaling parameters using [open-cv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66359569/14409072) if there is fixed a logo on your window/frame. 

You can update the question with a picture of the window/frame you want to capture if you want that type of solution. `pyautogui` has no inherent way of capturing just a window