# Clicking NEXT to Images

Tags: python, selenium, automation, pyautogui

I have had some success automating some work navigating a website lately, but I've had a *LOT* of difficulty trying to get it to work across multiple systems.

Currently, I am using PyAutoGUI to locate an image of text, and then telling Python to click to the RIGHT of that image in order to select the desired text box. Unfortunately, this isn't panning out to other systems even with lowered confidence intervals for the locateOnScreen() method.

I tried looking into Selenium to locate the text, but unfortunately I would have to run this on an existing IE explorer which is currently unsupported.

I was thinking about using OCR, but I'm unsure of how I would tell Python to click NEXT the the text that I am searching for.

Any input on possible solutions would be greatly appreciated!

-MontX

**Edit**:

Image of what I've been trying to get PyAutoGUI to recognize.

Example of text I've been trying to locate on screen:
[image: Example of text I've been trying to locate on screen.]

Example of kind of icons I've been trying to locate on screen:
[image: Example of kind of icons I've been trying to locate on screen.]

Comment: Well, since you didn't present here any relevant details the answer is: I guess you should make some coding for that

Comment: I'm relatively new to coding. My first thought is to have PyTesseract find the text using OCR and then maybe try to have PyAutoGUI take a picture and then click next to that. Are there any glaring issues with this?

Comment: To answer questions here we need to know all the possible details: the web site link, the code you already wrote, what works for you and what still not, what error do you get and for what code line etc.

Comment: Ah I see. I don't think I can share my code yet, but I may send pieces of it once I explore the above idea. Thank you!

Comment: What did you mean by other systems? Could you show me a image example? I have worked with automation projects where I first searched for a specific image and then click in certain place when found

Comment: pyautogui's `locateOnScreen` is possibly failing because of different screen resolutions. The image of text you are trying to locate has different sizes on different systems. Try using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66359569/14409072) modified function to locate images independent of the scale.

Comment: Hi Shahriar! I meant other systems as in other people's computers. I want to be able to use this code on my computer and others. I attached an image as another thread. Basically it's just an image of text on the website.

Comment: PG11, that's amazing! I'm going to check it out. Hopefully this works because it'll save me a lot of time trying to use Tesseract to locate the text on screen.

Comment: Hi everyone! I updated this question with more code, images, and specifics. I also tried to implement your code PG11, but I'm having some difficulty with getting an accurate match.

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68595891/multi-scale-template-match-vs-text-detection