# Multi-scale template match vs. Text Detection

Tags: python, opencv, automation, tesseract, pyautogui

I'm trying to automate the navigation of a website to grab data and download files using PyAutoGUI to detect images and buttons, but I'm having trouble using this on other people's computers. It seems to me that **matching images of text** is the biggest obstacle here.

I suspected the issue to be with scaling and resolution so I attempted using multi-scale template matching, but I found that using a template I upscaled wouldn't create a match at all. Using a template I downscaled didn't help either since it would either not find any matches, or find the wrong match even with a small range of confidences of 0.8-0.9.

Here's the original image at 74x17.

[image: original image]

Here's the **up**scaled image at 348x80 (Windows Photo wouldn't let me upscale it any smaller for some reason).

[image: upscaled image]

Here's the **down**scaled image at 40x8.

[image: downscaled image]

Currently, with a **down**scaled image, PyAutoGUI is confusing the above image with this image:

[image]

Here's the code I wrote (and some I borrowed from someone.

Code for multi-scaling I borrowed:

```
# Functions to search for resized versions of images
def template_match_with_scaling(image,gs=True,confidence=0.8):

# Locate an image and return a pyscreeze box surrounding it. 
# Template matching is done by default in grayscale (gs=True)
# Detect image if normalized correlation coefficient is > confidence (0.8 is default)

    templateim = pyscreeze._load_cv2(image,grayscale=gs)        # loads the image
    (tH, tW)   = templateim.shape[:2]       # changes the orientation
    screenim_color = pyautogui.screenshot()     # screenshot of image
    screenim_color = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(screenim_color),cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

    # Checking if the locateOnScreen() is utilized with grayscale=True or not
    if gs is True:
       screenim = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(screenim_color),cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    else:
       screenim = screenim_color

    #try different scaling parameters and see which one matches best
    found = None #bookeeping variable for the maximum correlation coefficient, position and scale
    scalingrange = np.linspace(0.25,5,num=150)

    for scale in scalingrange:
        print("Trying another scale")
        resizedtemplate = imutils.resize(templateim,  width = int(templateim.shape[1]*scale) ) # resizing with  imutils maintains the aspect ratio
        r = float(resizedtemplate.shape[1])/templateim.shape[1] # recompute scaling factor
        result = cv2.matchTemplate(screenim, resizedtemplate, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED) # template matching using the correlation coefficient
        (_, maxVal, _, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(result) #returns a 4-tuple which includes the minimum correlation value, the maximum correlation value, the (x, y)-coordinate of the minimum value, and the (x, y)-coordinate of the maximum value
        if found is None or maxVal > found[0]:
           found = (maxVal, maxLoc, r)
           
    (maxVal, maxLoc, r) = found
    if maxVal > confidence:
       box = pyscreeze.Box(int(maxLoc[0]), int(maxLoc[1]), int(tW*r), int(tH*r) )
       return box
    else:
       return None

def locate_center_with_scaling(image,gs=True):
    loc = template_match_with_scaling(image,gs=gs) 
    if loc:
       return pyautogui.center(loc)
    else:
       raise Exception("Image not found")
```

My code to match and click on a textbox next to its identifier:

```
while SKUnoCounter <= len(listOfSKUs):

    while pyautogui.locateOnScreen('DescriptionBox-RESIZEDsmall.png', grayscale=True, confidence=0.8 ) is None:
        print("Looking for Description Box.")

        if locate_center_with_scaling('DescriptionBox-RESIZEDsmall.png') is not None:
            print("Found a resized version of Description Box. ")

            #Calling to function
            DB_x, DB_y = locate_center_with_scaling('DescriptionBox-RESIZEDsmall.png')
            
            #Clicking on Description text box
            pyautogui.click( DB_x + 417,  DB_y +12,  button='left')
            
            break
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Is it worthwhile to try and improve the accuracy of the multi-scale template matching if my goal is to use this across all kinds of computers? Would it be better to try using OCR to detect text instead of by image? My other idea here is to use PyTesseract to locate the text I'm searching for and then use those coordinates to click on things. Selenium does not work here as I need to work on an existing IE browser.

Any input here is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your code works fine with `DescriptionBox-RESIZEDlarge.png`. It is unable to detect the small description box because it does not have the same aspect ratio as the original image. You will have to modify `template_match_with_scaling` to scale the width and height independently

Answer (score 1):

Following my comment above, this is how the modified function could look like

```py
# Functions to search for resized versions of images
def template_match_with_scaling(image,gs=True,confidence=0.8, scalingrange=None):

# Locate an image and return a pyscreeze box surrounding it. 
# Template matching is done by default in grayscale (gs=True)
# Detect image if normalized correlation coefficient is > confidence (0.8 is default)
    templateim = pyscreeze._load_cv2(image,grayscale=gs)        # loads the image
    (tH, tW)   = templateim.shape[:2]       # changes the orientation
    screenim_color = pyautogui.screenshot()     # screenshot of image
    screenim_color = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(screenim_color),cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

    # Checking if the locateOnScreen() is utilized with grayscale=True or not
    if gs is True:
       screenim = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(screenim_color),cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    else:
       screenim = screenim_color

    #try different scaling parameters and see which one matches best
    found = None #bookeeping variable for the maximum correlation coefficient, position and scale
    
    for scalex in scalingrange:
      width = int(templateim.shape[1] * scalex) 
      for scaley in scalingrange:
        #print("Trying another scale")
        #print(scalex,scaley)
        height = int(templateim.shape[0] * scaley)
        scaledsize = (width, height)
 
        # resize image
        resizedtemplate = cv2.resize(templateim, scaledsize)
        #resizedtemplate = imutils.resize(templateim,  width = int(templateim.shape[1]*scale) ) # resizing with  imutils maintains the aspect ratio
        ry = float(resizedtemplate.shape[1])/templateim.shape[1] # recompute scaling factor
        rx = float(resizedtemplate.shape[0])/templateim.shape[0] # recompute scaling factor
        result = cv2.matchTemplate(screenim, resizedtemplate, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED) # template matching using the correlation coefficient
        (_, maxVal, _, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(result) #returns a 4-tuple which includes the minimum correlation value, the maximum correlation value, the (x, y)-coordinate of the minimum value, and the (x, y)-coordinate of the maximum value
        if found is None or maxVal > found[0]:
           found = (maxVal, maxLoc, rx, ry)
           
    (maxVal, maxLoc, rx, ry) = found
    print('maxVal= ', maxVal)
    if maxVal > confidence:
       box = pyscreeze.Box(int(maxLoc[0]), int(maxLoc[1]), int(tW*rx), int(tH*ry) )
       return box
    else:
       return None

def locate_center_with_scaling(image,gs=True,**kwargs):
    loc = template_match_with_scaling(image,gs=gs,**kwargs) 
    if loc:
       return pyautogui.center(loc)
    else:
       raise Exception("Image not found")

im =  'DescriptionBox.png' # we will try to detect the small description box, whose width and height are scaled down by 0.54 and 0.47              
unscaledLocation = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(im, grayscale=True, confidence=0.8 )
srange = np.linspace(0.4,0.6,num=20) #scale width and height in this range
if unscaledLocation is None:
   print("Looking for Description Box.")
   scaledLocation = locate_center_with_scaling(im, scalingrange= srange)   
   if scaledLocation is not None:
      print(f'Found a resized version of Description Box at ({scaledLocation[0]},{scaledLocation[1]})')
      pyautogui.moveTo(scaledLocation[0], scaledLocation[1])
```

We need to be mindful of two things:

- `template_match_with_scaling` is now executing a double loop, one over each dimension so it will take some time to detect the template image. To amortize the detection time, we should save the scale parameters for width and height after the first detection, and scale all template images by these parameters for subsequent detections.
- to be able to detect the template efficiently, we need to set the `scalingrange` input of `template_match_with_scaling` to an appropriate range of values. If the range is either small or doesn't have enough values, we will not be able to detect the template. If it is too large, detection time will be large.

Comment: Whoa this is great! I worked on PyTesseract shortly after posting this question and it somewhat works so I'm going to explore that avenue a little more before I go down this route because I feel text detection may be a little more stable here. 
Thank you for your help!